# How can i use LAN for file sharing and exchanging?

Tags: lan, file-sharing

I want to know that how can I download and upload files from a local network?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this : Stepwise guide to share file on LAN - http://hubpages.com/hub/File-sharing-on-LAN

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify what OS your running ?. If its windows they provide workgroups and shared folders which you can specify control (I dont have windows at the minute to test it out). If its linux to linux you can use NFS(http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/) if its linux to windows you can use samba (http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html). Not sure about mac .